# Is there an API for Power BI for Office 365 admin center?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerbi

Is there a public API for Power BI for Office 365?

I have searched for a Power BI API, however, the only results are related to the new Power BI experience which is still in preview.

I found this question on the technet forums, but, the answer only links to the API for the new Power BI.

> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b15de752-353f-48f2-a890-9cee2f3e7ebc/public-api-for-power-bi-for-office-365?forum=powerbiforoffice365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no Public API for Power BI for O365.   The next version of Power BI (i.e. the Power BI Preview) is extensible with APIs.   You can find more about them at http://dev.powerbi.com

Answer (score 0):

Let me check on that. I'm not aware of one right off the top of my head.

-Lukasz

- http://dev.powerbi.com
- http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev
- Sign up for Power BI: http://www.powerbi.com